# transformation of uniform random variables

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, uniform-distribution, pit

Let $U_1, U_2,...,U_n$ be a sequence of independent random variables with Uniform distribution over the interval $(0, 1)$ and let  $Y = -\frac{1}{\lambda} log(U_1)$ . what is the distribution of Y? i have a feeling this is exponential because I think  Y  can be seen as an exponential quantile. how to prove this result if my idea is correct?

then for the second question can you provide  an hint since I have no clue?
Determine the range $A$ of the random variable $Y$ ,and for all $y  \in A $ compute $P(Y\le A)$

Comment: Hint: algebra tells you $\Pr(Y\le A)=\Pr(U_1\ge \exp(-\lambda A)).$

Comment: If you're still not sure, then [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=uniform+exponential+distribution+log+exp).

Comment: I got it!, based on this Can I conclude that $Y$ is exponential distribuited? the range $A$ shouldn't be from $0$ to $\infty$ ?